# Not able to install pandas-datareader in Python spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have been trying to install pandas-datareader but I am facing a syntax error.

I am using Anaconda Spyder 3.1.2

Code:

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-25-4ea57f630f45>", line 1
    pip install pandas-datareader
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried `conda install pandas-datareader` but same issue..

==============================

Today (13-07-2017) As per your solution i tried to do it in CMD but got these errors  in screenshot(PFA)

[installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bv07.png)

Kindly  help..

Comment: Running pip or conda commands inside a Python or IPython console in Spyder doesn't work. Please open a system terminal (bash or cmd.exe) and run them there instead.

Comment: As per your suggestion i try to do in CMD but facing error.. Screenshot of error is attached in my question... Please help..

Comment: It seems you have a certificate problem that prevents you from installing things with pip. What happens if you try to run `conda install pandas-datareader`?

Comment: Thanks very much.. it seems to be worked...

Comment: For next time, please try to use conda before pip. It's usually not a good idea to mix both of them in the same environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering the same code (pip install pandas-datareader) In the terminal instead of python shell.

Comment: As per your suggestion i try to do in CMD but facing error.. Screenshot of error is attached in my question... Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if you have `pip` installed, if not, have a look [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)):

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

or you can use `conda` it should work as well:

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

Don't forgot that you should use this command line in a terminal

Comment: As per your suggestion i try to do in CMD but facing error.. Screenshot of error is attached in my question... Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

use
`!pip install pandas-datareader`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue

I use Anaconda...I opened a juptyer notbook session and ran a code pip install pandas-datareader

it worked .  I closed it and ran the datareader in sypder and it was fine